# How to change freeglut main window icon in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi, icons, glut, freeglut

I have a DLL written in C++ that uses FreeGlut to visualize some data. I want to change the icon of the main (free)glut window.

I've read that it is impossible, but in the docs I see:

> GLUT_ICON - specifies the icon that goes in the upper left-hand corner of the freeglut windows.

How can I change icon for (free)glut window, if possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I did it:

1. Create a Resource for the project and add an 32x32 icon (edit it or import). This icon will get the ID equal to `IDI_ICON1`.
2. Include the "resource.h" file.
3. Create the glut window like this:

   ```
   glutCreateWindow("VIZ"); 
   HWND hwnd = FindWindow(NULL, _T("VIZ") ); //probably you can get the window handler in different way..
   ```

Now get the icon - it is in your DLL file, with IDI_ICON1 id, so we use:

```
    HANDLE icon = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(_T("NAME_OF_YOUR_DLL")),  MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_ICON1), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32,  LR_COLOR );
    //You can also prepare second, smaller (16x16) icon - it looks better in title bar. 
    //...
```

Now send this message to the Window.

```
    SendMessage(hwnd, (UINT)WM_SETICON, ICON_BIG, (LPARAM)icon);
```

That's it! Probably some cleaning would be nice.

This solution does not require to deploy .ico file. If you prefer you can ommit resource file and load icon with:

```
    icon = LoadImage(GetModuleHandle(), _T("icon.ico"), IMAGE_ICON, 32, 32, LR_LOADFROMFILE | LR_COLOR);
```

You can also use [LoadIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, but then you can't select icon size.

Manuals:
[LoadImage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648045%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
[LoadIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

**Edit:**

I think it's not the best solution, so you're welcome to write yours. Maybe using `GLUT_ICON` ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, since you're disturbuting a DLL. If you are disturbuting an executable it can be simply done by set the GLUT_ICON or 0x1000, 0x1001, the windows way, and both without calling winapi to change the icon by hand, which is done by the linker.